# Counting rows with similar data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table that I generated with the following code:

```
fruit_characteristics = df.pivot_table(index=['fruit','characteristic1', 'characteristic2'], aggfunc='size').to_frame()
```

The results I get are:

```
fruit      characteristic1 characteristic2
apple       green           tart            1
            red             sweet           3
            yellow          sweet           1
grapefruit  bitter          yellow          1
            yellow          bitter          2
           bitter          yellow           1
orange      round           sweet           5
            sweet           round           1
pineapple   prickly         sweet           2
            sweet           prickly         2
watermelon  green           heavy           1
            heavy           green           2
```

So some of the results have similar characteristics in either column for example watermelon has char1 green char2 heavy and another row has char1 heavy char2 green.  is there a way i can add those as 1 since they are essentially the same characteristics ?

original data from the csv

```
fruit   days    characteristic1 characteristic2
apple   1   red sweet
orange  2   round   sweet
pineapple   5   prickly sweet
apple   4   yellow  sweet
grapefruit  2   yellow  bitter
watermelon  4   green   heavy
orange  2   round   sweet
orange  1   round   sweet
pineapple   6   prickly sweet
apple   1   green   tart
grapefruit  1   bitter  yellow
watermelon  2   heavy   green
grapefruit  2   bitter  yellow
watermelon  3   heavy   green
orange  1   round   sweet
orange  5   sweet   round
pineapple   2   sweet   prickly
apple   2   red sweet
orange  6   round   sweet
pineapple   2   sweet   prickly
apple   1   red sweet
grapefruit  3   yellow  bitter
```

Comment: can you provide the data from before the pivot

Comment: I added the original data in the csv above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could swap the 2 characteristic columns to make sure that they have a constant order before pivoting:

```
df.loc[df['characteristic1']>df['characteristic2'], ['characteristic1', 'characteristic2']] = \
    df.loc[df['characteristic1']>df['characteristic2'], ['characteristic2', 'characteristic1']].values

fruit_characteristics = df.pivot_table(index=['fruit','characteristic1', 'characteristic2'], aggfunc='size').to_frame()
```

With your example data, it gives:

```
                                            0
fruit      characteristic1 characteristic2   
apple      green           tart             1
           red             sweet            3
           sweet           yellow           1
grapefruit bitter          yellow           4
orange     round           sweet            6
pineapple  prickly         sweet            4
watermelon green           heavy            3
```